# During sign ups, how to best instill confidence that email addresses will be safe

Tags: website-design, user-behavior, copywriting, email, security

Many sign up forms will ask you for an email address so that they can contact you.

Even the most minimal sign-up (other than *no* sign up) will need an email address to send you a validation email.

Frequently we see copy that says

- we will never send you spam
  *(well that depends on what you consider spam... unsolicited emails about discouts)*
- we will never sell or rent your email address
  *(incomplete, eg doesn't preclude actually giving it away)*
- we will only ever use your email address to communicate with you about your orders
  *(really - that's a bit restrictive actually)*

Occasionally we get a light hearted or casual message like this one from Wufoo, which seems like a good option, but is casual really the best approach?

[image]

Sometimes we see links to *Privacy policies* or *terms and conditions*, that few people actually read.

Or maybe the matter should not even be raised in the user's mind?

**What's the best way during a sign-up process, to instill confidence in a user that their valuable email address is safe?**

Comment: don't ask for an email, use OAuth instead

Comment: A cute little "we hate spam as much as you"  seems okay to me, but on times I've seen it devolve into [this](http://websule.com/privacy-policy/we-hate-spam)

Comment: @NaoiseGolden ok, maybe that's an option in some cases - but for the sake of this question - let's assume we need the email address... :-)

Comment: @RogerAttrill Unfortunately I think most users don't care what text you put there. It boils down to the user either caring about what the site has to offer and thus engaging in a real relationship or not. I follow varying approaches depending on the sites _worth_, ie...don't post phone number so they contact me via email, provide one time email for registration confirmation, etc... You may _want_ my email but more often than not you don't _need_ my email and that's the frustrating part.

Comment: also, the best form to instill confidence on the form, rather than coming from the tip line, comes from the whole site. If a warez site is telling me "we hate spam" I will give them a bogus email anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Long, boring documents

You are right, the average user does not read privacy policies or terms & conditions. *But that doesn't mean you shouldn't include them* in a visible, obvious location on the signup page (and typically in small text at the bottom of every other page as well).

## Man or Machine

The best practice I find for instilling confidence in a user is to **write your communication to the user as if you are a real person**. The "casual message" from Wufoo above is a great example. Why is this so? People are *inundated* with loads of technical speech on the internet, and at most (typical) sign-up pages. It literally feels to them as if some soul-less computer generated the text and spat it out. Writing in a more casual, friendly manner can give the user confidence that you are a **real person, just like them** and that your promise to keep their email safe is actually true.

So what I would do is the short and sweet casual message (as in the example above), but also include before the "Sign Up!" button itself a clear link to the privacy policy should the user require more detail. This way you are being inviting to everyone and still provide the details for the more technical users.